# unexpected token `newline'\n/bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash ansible snowsql

Tags: bash, ansible, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to write ansible playbook to install snowsql on a machine. Getting following error:

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'\n/bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'"
```

Tried to run `snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash` manually but that gave an error:

```
ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ bash snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash 
snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

then realized that `1.2.7` is a recently released version.

tried to install the previous once `1.2.3` and `1.2.5` and was able to install them manually. But when i try to install them using ansible like following:-

```
name: install installer
  command: bash "{{snowsql_installation_directory}}"/"{{snowsql_version}}".bash
  become: yes
```

i constantly keep getting error as following :-

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["bash", "/bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash"], "delta": "0:00:00.003428", "end": "2020-06-30 21:15:15.085449", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2020-06-30 21:15:15.082021", "stderr": "/bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'\n/bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'", "/bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

I have noticed the new snowsql installer needs a user input called destination

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ bash snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash       **********************************************************************
 Installing SnowSQL, Snowflake CLI.
**********************************************************************

Specify the directory in which the SnowSQL components will be installed. [~/bin] 
Do you want to add /home/ec2-user/bin to PATH in /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile? [y/N] y
```

is ansible throwing this error because it is not receiving any input from user for this?

the version 1.2.7 throwing the same error makes me feel that it is something to do with the binary and not the code. pretty new to snowsql so would appreciate all the help i can get

Comment: /bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash prob. contains DOS CR's. Filter through `sed 's/\015$//g'  < /bin/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.bash > snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64-unix.bash`.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ bash snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash 
snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The error complains that the first line is not interpretable by the Bash shell, which makes sense because it reports what appears to be an XML document header, which a bash script file isn't supposed to contain:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The resolution will depend on how you're downloading this script file. Inspect that step if it is automated, to ensure that the downloaded file contains exactly what you were expecting. You can view your current file to determine what it really is instead of the script:

```sh
~> cat /bin/snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64-unix.bash
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[ … ]
```

If you're using curl to fetch the script from [Snowflake's client repository](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowflake-client-repository.html), the following should work in fetching the exact file (ensure to add proxy settings if your environment requires one, as otherwise it'll return something you aren't expecting):

```sh
# Download directly to /bin/snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash
# Uses the fail option to detect if something, such as a proxy, rejected or interfered with the HTTP(S) GET request
~> curl --silent --fail https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash -O /bin/snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash

# If download succeeds, ensure the first line is a shbang line indicating a proper script download
~> head -1 /bin/snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.bash
#!/bin/bash -e
```

Comment: Including `--fail` in your `curl` command will be more helpful, since that will prevent curl from writing out a file for a non-200 response (which is likely what happened in the first place: AWS sent back a 403 and their access denied XML, which curl cheerfully wrote to disk)